# Unit Testing Mock Service Impl

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I have a service and serviceImpl too in a spring boot application. When I want to test it and trying to mock my service in junit test class I got `NullPointerException` error.

**here is my service impl**

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Date;

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Override
    public MyObject doSomething(Date date) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**and here is my test class**

```
package com.test;

import com.netflix.discovery.shared.Application;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNull;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-integrationtest.properties")
class MyServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    MyService myservice;

    @Test
    void doSomethingTest() {
        assertNull(myservice.doSomething(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested with your code and no exception was thrown...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize your mocks, when using `@Mock` annotations. You can do it in method annotated with `@Before`:

```
@Before public void initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Alternatively you can change your runner from `SpringRunner` to:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Edit:

Also you have to create a bean from your implementation:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService
```

Comment: the myservice object is null yet

Comment: Thanks for your replies. but it doesn't work yet. I added @Service. then added @Before method.does not work. change @RunWith parameter to  `MockitoJUnitRunner` and added service.does not work

Comment: Can you paste the whole class, where `@SpringBootApplication` is?

Comment: ```@SpringBootApplication
public class ContradictionApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        SpringApplication.run(ContradictionApplication.class, args);
    }
}

```

Comment: ```package com.irisa.pay.contradiction;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.util.TimeZone;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ContradictionApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        SpringApplication.run(ContradictionApplication.class, args);
    }
}

```

Comment: That's why I asked for editing question. You need to move service and impl to subpackage of  `ContradictionApplication `

Comment: it was. but i change package to generalize question :). the service impl real package is package com.irisa.pay.contradiction.day;

Comment: And the interface?

Comment: same package of serviceimpl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189856/discussion-between-sina-salmani-and-andronicus).